# When will reputation re-calculation be finished for this site?

Tags: support, reputation

Stack Exchange recently announced that it'll reward question askers more and so a reputation re-calculation will happen.

[We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

I welcome this decision because I believe I'll get most benefit out of it on this site. I am just curious to know when I can expect to see re-calculated reputation on this site.

**EDIT:**
New re-calculated reputation is now live on this site. I am now in 100K club (previous rep: ~60K). My legendary badge progress has also jumped from ~20 to 99.

Comment: "*I believe I'll get most benefit out of it on this site*" - there's probably a Data.SE query for that, but I'm guessing DVK and Sly will also make significant gains, as well as Major Stackings, ASR, and myself.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Not easy to calculate using Data.SE given rep cap is also being taken into account.

Comment: I don't appear to have gained that much. I don't ask a lot of questions...

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy between two places where the amount of reputation is given (one just next to your square "avatar", the other visible only when your click on the rightmost icon. These amounts were always equal before !

Comment: @Randal'Thor Rep cap has been taken into account. My legendary badge progress has increased significantly.

Comment: Congrats on your new 100k, I guess. (Meanwhile, over on [puzzling.se], I got back to #1 user and the site's first Legendary badge.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Wow! How much did you gain on this site?

Comment: @CaptainCold Around 11k here, 12k on Puzzling, 8.5k on [literature.se], a few more thousands elsewhere.

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Don’t forget about me, old friend.  I’ve made significant gains, too, as a result of this (around 9K).  In particular, I’m *finally* in the 100K club with you.

Comment: @Praxis Hey, long time no see! I [noticed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58631?m=52549603#52549603) you'd hit 100k, but you weren't pingable in chat. Unfortunately SE hasn't been sending out any swag for the last year or so, so you'll have to make do with the glory of the 6-figure rep. Congrats :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Thanks for the congratulatory mention (been a long while since I’ve looked at chat)!  I always figured by the time I had 100K that there would be no swag, but that’s okay!  Hope you’re doing well.  :-)

Comment: @Valorum it’s all very relative—you’ve asked more questions than I have questions and answers combined :P

Comment: weird - I would have expected to get a lot more than I apparently got based on my rough calculations. Did it only run for a specific subset of users?

Comment: @NKCampbell Did you take rep cap into account?

Comment: oh - I guess that would be it :(  bye bye 5k points :D  - thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When they fix the problems with it on MSE as explained by [Jon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338119/regarding-the-recalc-in-question-rep-increase-what-happens-due-to-the-cap#comment1125454_338124). It will run sometimes after that.

> Yes it is, but for now it's just on MSE. We're working through some problems as we speak. — Jon Ericson ♦

---

The rep recalc appears to have finished for SFF now. There were lots of items to process so it was taking its time. As current events are coming in now to the top bar, which was going to happen after the recalc finished its safe to say it has done.

Comment: Rep re-calculation is already finished.

Comment: I was wondering why my reputation suddenly doubled out of nowhere for no reasons. Don't know what to think about it, uh...

Comment: @Captain Cold There is still discrepancy between the reputation value as it appears just on the left of the square "avatar"  (for the community you are actually visiting - SF&F now) and the value for SF&F when you click on the rightmost icon, where your standing for all the communities you belong to. There is no such discrepancies for the my other communities, and also for SF&F it only appeared recently, when I noticed a huge jump in my reputation (from just less than 1000 to more than 1600 - I just spent 100 on a bounty) but it is still there now.

Comment: @Captain Cold Now the bugs seem to have been corrected. The reputation is now exactly the same just on the right (not the left!) of the square "avatar", and when one clicks on the rightmost icon, for the SF&F community as well as my two others. Thanks for the 600+ points I got !

Comment: @Clockwork I just noticed this question yesterday. (Don't spend much time on Meta.) Like you, I had recently wondered why I seemed to have picked up approx. 5000 points,in a hurry, but I hadn't been very worried about it.